# How to put knockback on bullet unity2D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, destroy

How can I make it so that when a bullet hits an object it gives it knockback and that it destroys itself/vanishes?

I have done some research but I couldn't find the answer. the only way I found to do knockback is to just live the bullet hit the object normally and it gives it knockback with its mass but the bullet stays floating around.

weapon code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
    
public class Weapon : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform firePoint;
    public float fireRate = 15f;
    public GameObject bulletPrefab;
    public Transform  MuzzleFlashPrefab;
    public AudioSource sfx;
    private float nextTimeToFire = 0f;
    [HideInInspector] public audio currentGunData;
                   
    void Update() 
    {    
        if (Input.GetButton("Fire1") && Time.time >= nextTimeToFire)
        {
            nextTimeToFire = Time.time + 1f/fireRate;
            Shoot();
            //sound
            sfx.Stop();
            sfx.clip = currentGunData.gunshotSound;
            sfx.pitch = 1 - currentGunData.pitchRandomization + Random.Range(-currentGunData.pitchRandomization,currentGunData.pitchRandomization);
            sfx.Play();           
        }
    }
          
    void Shoot()
    {
        Instantiate(bulletPrefab, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation);
        Transform clone = Instantiate (MuzzleFlashPrefab, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation) as Transform;
        clone.parent = firePoint;
        float size = Random.Range (0.02f, 0.025f);
           
        clone.localScale = new Vector3 (size, size, size);
        Destroy (clone.gameObject, 0.056f);
    }              
}
```

bullet code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class bulet : MonoBehaviour
{       
    public float speed = 40f;
    public Rigidbody2D rb;
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rb.velocity = transform.right * speed;
    }  
}
```

the object I'm shooting at

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class stickmancontroler : MonoBehaviour
{
    public _Muscle[] muscles;
  
    // Update is called once per frame
    private void Update()
    {
        foreach (_Muscle muscle in muscles)
        {
            muscle.ActivateMuscle();
        }
    }
}

[System.Serializable]
public class _Muscle
{
   public Rigidbody2D bone;
   public float restRotation;
   public float force;

   public void ActivateMuscle()
   {
      bone.MoveRotation(Mathf.LerpAngle(bone.rotation, restRotation, force * Time.deltaTime));
    }  
}
```

my attempt of putting knockback

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
    
public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float knockbackaPower = 100;
    public float knockbackDuration = 1;
    private static Player instance;
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private void Awake()
    {
        instance = this;
    }
    
    void Start()
    {            
    }
      
    void Update()
    {          
    }
          
    void OnTriggerEnter2D (Collider2D col)
    {
        if(col.gameObject.name == "bulet")
        {
            Debug.Log("hti");
        }       
    }      
    
    private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
    {        
        if(other.gameObject.tag == "bullet")  
        {    
            StartCoroutine(Knockback(knockbackDuration, knockbackaPower, this.transform));
        }          
    }
         
    public IEnumerator Knockback(float knockbackDuration, float knockbackaPower, Transform obj)
    {
        float timer = 0;
    
        while (knockbackDuration > timer)
        {
            timer += Time.deltaTime;
            Vector2 direction = (obj.transform.position - this.transform.position).normalized;
            Debug.Log(rb);
            rb.AddForce(-direction * knockbackaPower);
        }
        yield return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please use the correct tags! Note that [`unityscript`](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/unityscript/info) is or better **was** a JavaScript flavor like custom language used in early Unity versions and is long **deprecated** by now! Your code is clearly `c#` and is also completely unrelated to `knockback.js`

Answer (score 1):

What is your coroutine good for if you only `yield` at the very end? If you want to spread your `while` loop over multiple frames you have to `yield return null;` within it!

And you could simply call `Destroy(other.gameObject);` the moment you start the knockback so the bullet is immediately destroyed whenever it hits something. Simply pre-cache it's position/ the knockback direction instead of repeatedly calculate every iteration beforehand.

```
private void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
{  
    // In general rather use CompareTag instead of string ==
    // it is slightly faster and avoids typos since it would throw an error instead of silently fail       
    if(other.gameObject.ComapareTag("bullet")) 
    {  
        // Here you want to pass in the OTHER transform (the one of the bullet)
        // and NOT your own one!  
        StartCoroutine(Knockback(knockbackDuration, knockbackaPower, other.transform));
    }          
}
     
private IEnumerator Knockback(float knockbackDuration, float knockbackaPower, Transform bullet)
{
    var direction = (bullet.transform.position - transform.position).normalized;

    // As soon as you have all relevant values destroy the bullet immediately after a hit
    Destroy(bullet);

    var timer = 0f;  
    while (timer < knockbackDuration)
    {
        rb.AddForce(-direction * knockbackaPower);

        // You need to yield INSIDE the while loop
        // otherwise it is fully performed within one single frame
        timer += Time.deltaTime;
        yield return null;
    }
}
```

Now if instead of actually letting the onbects collide (which should already cause some knockback without the need of your Coroutine) you could instead actually make it a **Trigger** and rather actually calculate the force from theass and impact velocity of the bullet

```
private IEnumerator OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if(!other.CompareTag("bullet") || !other.TryGetComponent<Rigidbody2D>(out var bulletRb)) yield break; 

    // Calculate the knock force caused by the bullet's mass and velocity
    var speedSqr = bullerRb.velcotiy.sqrMagnitude;
    var direction = bullerRb.velcotiy.normalized;
    var force = 0.5f * bulletRb.mass * speedSqr * direction;
    Destroy(other.gameObject);
    
    rb.AddForce(force, ForceMode.Impulse);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use OnCollisionExit2D() to destroy the bullet only after it is no longer in collision with the object. That way you can leave the bullet to hit the object normally and give it knockback with its mass.